# Change of jqgrid theme not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code, which work fine locally.  Iwas trying to change the bootstrap theme  to one of the jqgrid [themes](http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/component/phocagallery/category/1-themes). I looked online for theme changing and it didnt seem to work .

Here is my code below and [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/sj4mtbv1/1/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a Boostrap  and jqGrid Bootstrap CSS siles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
    <script>
        $.jgrid.defaults.width = 780;
        $.jgrid.defaults.responsive = true;     
        $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap';
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jLp data </title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:20px">
    <table id="nplGrid"></table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#nplGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'json/data-bcp.json',
                datatype: "json",
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Id', name: 'Id', width: 45 },
                    { label: 'Symbol', name: 'Symbol', width: 90 },
                    { label: 'Quantity', name: 'Quantity', width: 100 },
                    /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                        name: 'Value1', 
                        width: 80, 
                        sorttype: 'number', 
                        formatter: 'number',
                        align: 'right'
                    }, */
                    { label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 80, sorttype: 'integer' },
                    { label: 'Value', name: 'Value', width: 80, sorttype: 'integer' },
                    { label: 'Pledged', name: 'Pledged', width: 80, sorttype: 'integer' }  
                ],
                loadonce: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                footerrow: true,
                 caption: "<b>Brokerage Client Portfolio</b>",
                hidegrid:false,
                userDataOnFooter: true, // use the userData parameter of the JSON response to display data on footer                
                height: 170,
                altRows: true,  
                rowNum: 150
            });

        });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not full clear for me, which product, in which version and with which theme you want to use. The owner of http://jqgrid.com site is unclear for me. The page with themes, which you reference, uses just different [jQuery UI Themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and have no relation to Bootstrap. There are currently two forks of jqGrid which both supports Bootstrap: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). You demo uses old jqGrid 4.6, which doesn't support Bootstrap.

Comment: @oleg - I want to remove the bootstrap theme and use the default light blueish theme of jqgrid. How can i do that?

Comment: What you mean under "default light blueish theme"? There are the following standard theme: black-tie, blitzer, cupertino, dark-hive, dot-luv, eggplant, excite-bike, flick, hot-sneaks, humanity, le-frog, mint-choc, overcast, pepper-grinder, redmond, smoothness, south-street, start, sunny, swanky-purse, trontastic, ui-darkness, ui-lightness, and vader. For example **start**, **redmond** and **cupertino** are light blue. Look [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data) an example of the usage. You can replace `themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css` to another one.

Comment: for example https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/3/ uses "redmon" theme. The same code, but with "cupertino": https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/4/. Another one https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/5/ with "start" theme and so on. One need just uses the URL to the corresponding theme.